# Hsaura docker-compose file is returning an error - exited with code 0

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hasura

This is the docker compose file. The only thing I have changed is adding a command so that hasura would wait until the website is up before spinning up the image.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  graphql-engine:
    container_name: "prm_graphql_engine"
    image: hasura/graphql-engine:v1.3.0
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    command: >
      sh -c "
      until wget --spider host.docker.internal:8000; do
        >&2 echo 'Django is unavailable - sleeping'
        sleep 5
      done;
        echo 'Django is up'
      "
    depends_on:
      - "db"
      - "web"
    restart: always
    environment:
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL: postgres://$POSTGRES_USER:$POSTGRES_PASSWORD@db:5432/$POSTGRES_NAME
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE: "true" # set to "false" to disable console
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLED_LOG_TYPES: startup, http-log, webhook-log, websocket-log, query-log
```

When I run docker-compose up verbose, here is the error message.

```
prm_graphql_engine exited with code 0
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "POST /v1.38/containers/d3be369d69af7de6cd5dc84f0056dda49fce7f474b827e78e518144dca8e03d5/wait HTTP/1.1" 200 None
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.38/containers/d3be369d69af7de6cd5dc84f0056dda49fce7f474b827e78e518144dca8e03d5/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {'AppArmorProfile': '',
 'Args': ['-c',
          ' until wget --spider host.docker.internal:8000; do\n'
          "  >&2 echo 'Django is unavailable - sleeping'\n"
          '  sleep 5\n'
          'done;\n'
          "  echo 'Django is up'\n"],
 'Config': {'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- ('d3be369d69af7de6cd5dc84f0056dda49fce7f474b827e78e518144dca8e03d5')
```

Is there something I missed? I do need to wait for another container to run first but I don't see why the command would cause any error.

Answer (score 2):

Exit code `0` is success (easy to remember, all non-zero exit codes = failure).

It looks like what's happened here is that `command` in the `docker-compose.yaml` overrides the default command. And you've set the command to be:

```sh
until wget --spider host.docker.internal:8000; do
        >&2 echo 'Django is unavailable - sleeping'
        sleep 5
done;
echo 'Django is up'
```

Assuming that the `until` condition is met, and it goes on to `echo`, once it finishes that command would terminate with exit code `0`, and then end the container process (preventing Hasura from running).

I think you should use a `docker-entrypoint` script if you want to execute pre-start commands instead of overriding the container's command.

Comment: Thank you and this does answer my question. Could you share how to not override the original entrypoint or cmd? I have actually tried both and it seems like they both overrode the original cmd/entrypoint commands.